# Membership Report errors

Tags: civimember, civireport

Running Civi 4.4 on Drupal 7.34.

I have an organization with a LOT of membership types (they manage all their statewide chapters via a single install of Civi). There is a configuration in which four memberships are granted at once.

If I use Contact Advanced Search, I will pull up all the members who have purchased any of these four memberships: A or B or C or D. Works perfectly.

If I use a Detailed Membership Report to pull up these members, I only get a few of them.

If I go in and directly view the Contact, all the memberships are showing correctly.

So to recap:

If I build a query along the lines of "Show all contacts with membership A or B, new/current/grace", and NOTHING ELSE, I get a different number of results in Contact Advanced Search than I do in a Membership Detailed Report. Viewed side-by-side, the contacts otherwise look identical in terms of memberships and so on. It's the Membership Report that is not showing all the Contacts that have the membership in question.

I checked CiviMembership and all the memberships in question are live.

How do I determine why some of those contacts appear in one report but not the other, when the report criteria are identical? Totally baffled, help!